# What Is the Autonomy Search Engine

Tags: c#, .net, search-engine, article, autonomy

what is the autonomy Search Engine , is it a Computer Language (C# , PHP , VB , etc) or it's a Technic, or what is it .
 and if there a tutorial  or article for it  , kindly share it with me ,

Kindly & Best Regards

Comment: Are you referring to this: http://www.autonomy.com/content/Solutions/enterprise-search/index.en.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a software that allows you to search for structured as well for unstructured data within a database (that is an organized collection of data, I'm not talking about any specific DBMS).

You can interact with the engine by using its apis, or a dedicated interface.

Comment: is there any tutorial or article can help me in autonomy search engine
or any example on it ?